# How to distribute data with Python on a Sparkcluster

Tags: python, apache-spark, cluster-computing

Good evening dear stackoverflow-Community 
I've got following problem.
I've set up a cluster with cloudera for spark. 
There is a Clustermanager and three workernodes, they are not local. 
I want the cluster to execute my python programm on some data.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from time import time as t

def mapper(point, data):
    counter = 0
    for elem in data:
        dominate = False
        for i in range(len(elem)):
            if point[i] < elem[i]:
                dominate = True
        if dominate:
            counter += 1
    return (point,counter)


if __name__=="__main__":

    xx = np.array([-0.51, 51.2])
    yy = np.array([0.33, 51.6])
    means = [xx.mean(), yy.mean()]  
    stds = [xx.std() / 3, yy.std() / 3]
    corr = 0.8    # correlation
    covs = [[stds[0]**2          , stds[0]*stds[1]*corr], 
           [stds[0]*stds[1]*corr,           stds[1]**2]] 

    m = np.random.multivariate_normal(means, covs, 1000).T
    data = list(zip(m[0],m[1]))

    conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Naive_Spark")
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    data_rdd = sc.parallelize(data).partitionBy(3).persist()

    start = t()

    mapped = data_rdd.map(lambda x: mapper(x, data)).filter(lambda x: x[1] == len(data)-1).collect()    
    print(mapped)
    time = str(t()-start)
    print(mapped)
    with open('/home/.../Schreibtisch/Naive.txt','a') as f:
        f.write('Spark: ' + str(mapped) + ' in ' + time + ' ms\n\n')
    sc.stop()
    plt.scatter(*zip(*data))
    plt.show()
```

For the moment I create the data in my python-programm and on local this works fine.
Normally I send my code and some data in a textfile to my cluster and execute it with spark-submit.
My question is, how do I split my data so the three nodes are getting each a part of it to work with it.

Greetings
Sam

Answer (score 0):

Just:

- make file available on all nodes using for example HDFS
- read it using applicable method (like SparkContex.texFile)
- let Spark handle the rest.

Comment: But there must be a way to control the nodes, so I can shut down one of them, if I only want to use two of them.